# Combining select() and filter()

Tags: r, dplyr

Does it matter in which order I have `select()` and `filter()`? Can I have `select(filter())` or `filter(select())` depending on what I want?

Comment: If your select statement removes a variable you want to filter on then they won't be equivalent. Otherwise, I don't think the order will matter.

Comment: @eipi10 Please post this as an answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`filter` references column names. If your `select` statement removes (or renames) a column that you want to filter on, then they won't be equivalent. Otherwise, I don't think the order will matter, since `filter` can only remove rows and `select` can only remove columns. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

select(filter(mtcars, hp > 200), cyl, mpg)
```

> ```
>   cyl  mpg
> 1   8 14.3
> 2   8 10.4
> 3   8 10.4
> 4   8 14.7
> 5   8 13.3
> 6   8 15.8
> 7   8 15.0
> ```

```
filter(select(mtcars, cyl, mpg), hp > 200)
```

> Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) :    Evaluation error: object 'hp'
>   not found.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that will be relevant is the order of the operation. The one inside will happen before the one outside. So if you put select(filter()) it will first filter the data.frame, and then select the variables you want. If you run filter(select()), it will first select the variables, and then filter it.